# psql: How can I get a single json column in aggregation after a group by query

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate, psql

I am trying to get a single row for each group by clause in the query. Each SELECT output has a json in it. I am trying this:

```
SELECT MIN(C.json_column->'key') AS Key, A.field1, B.field2
    FROM json_table AS C
    LEFT JOIN another_table AS D ON D.id=C.id
    INNER JOIN another_table2 AS A ON A.id=D.col2
    INNER JOIN another_table3 AS B on B.id=D.col3
GROUP BY (A.field1, B.field2)
```

The joins do not matter here. The issue is that `MIN(C.json_column->'key')` is returning:

```
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Since I am grouping by 2 other fields, I had to aggregate the json field. But I only want the first (or any other) single json row. `MIN` seems to not work on json type. what can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) construct. [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dQgHy49Y):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON(A.field1, B.field2) 
    C.json_column->'key' AS Key, A.field1, B.field2
    FROM json_table AS C
    LEFT JOIN another_table AS D ON D.id=C.id
    INNER JOIN another_table2 AS A ON A.id=D.col2
    INNER JOIN another_table3 AS B on B.id=D.col3
ORDER BY A.field1, B.field2
```

This picks one `json_column` for each unique pair of `(A.field1, B.field2)`, discarding the rest. For this case, `min()`/`max()` aggregate workaround would work the same, but in general `distinct on` is more versatile: with more of columns, aggregates quickly lose performance sorting each secondary column separately and they also produce non-existent value combinations instead of real samples from the group.

Answer (score -1):

Operator [`->`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html) return JSON element as JSON, Use `->>` instead to return the JSON element as text then cast it to integer :

```
SELECT MIN((C.json_column->>'key')::int) AS Key, A.field1, B.field2
    FROM json_table AS C
    LEFT JOIN another_table AS D ON D.id=C.id
    INNER JOIN another_table2 AS A ON A.id=D.col2
    INNER JOIN another_table3 AS B on B.id=D.col3
GROUP BY (A.field1, B.field2)
```